# При каких условиях в C битовый сдвиг влево для знакового целого приводит к неопределенному поведению?

Tags: c, неопределённое-поведение

Ясное дело, что `<<` и `>>` не должны принимать справа отрицательное число, но дальше я ничего не понял.

Comment: А должен приводить?

Comment: Так вопрос про `<<` и `>>` или про "сдвиг влево"?

Comment: Про сдвиг влево)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под "сдвигом для знакового целого" подразумевается сдвиг, в котором "знаковым целым" является левый операнд, то стоит помнить, что левый операнд сдвига подвергается integer promotions. То есть даже если в выражении `a << b` значение `a` является знаковым, на некоторых экзотических платформах оно может стать беззнаковым после integer promotions.

Поэтому далее будем рассматривать выражение `a << b`, где `a` - значение после integer promotions и оно по-прежнему знаковое.

Битовый сдвиг влево `a << b` для знакового целого `a` приводит к неопределенному поведению когда

- `b < 0`
- Значение `b` превосходит битовую ширину `a` или равно ей
- `a < 0`
- При сдвиге произошло переполнение, т.е. значение a*2<sup>b</sup> (вычисленное математически верно) не помещается в диапазон типа `a`

Первые два пункта относятся ко всем сдвигам.

Выражаясь более приземленным языком, последние два пункта говорят, что нельзя *двигать влево* единицу в знаковом бите и нельзя *вдвигать справа* единицу в знаковый бит.

Comment: Если на платформе int имеет диапазон [-2^(n-1); +2^(n-1)-1], то это значит, что битовый сдвиг влево для такого int более, чем на 31 разряд, - является неопределенным поведением? Даже если в int все 32 бита равны нулю? Для упрощения будем считать, что int не имеет набивочных битов: 1 бит знака и 31 бит значения.

Comment: Ну так бы и сказали: n = 32. На такой платформе сдвигать на 31 влево можно именно и только нулевое значение. В противном случае - неопределенное поведение из-за переполнения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: А для сдвига вправо каковы условия возникновения неопределенного поведения?

Comment: @Максим: Для сдвига вправо - только первые два пункта вызывают неопределенное поведение и все. Сдвиг вправо отрицательного значения вызывает поведение *определяемое реализацией*.

Comment: Даже если сдвинуть вправо на кол-во битов, большее, чем имеется в типе?

Comment: @Максим Нет, конечно. Так нельзя. Я же сказал - первые два пункта относятся и к сдвигу вправо тоже.

Comment: Все это неопределенное поведение как-то слишком сильно осложняет жизнь(

Answer (score 4):

Вот что пишет стандарт:

> Значение результата операции `E1 << E2` есть значение `E1`, сдвинутое влево на `E2` битовых позиций; биты, остающиеся свободными, заполняются нулями. Если тип `E1` беззнаковый, то значение результата есть E1×2<sup>E2</sup>, взятое по модулю, на единицу большему, чем максимальное значение, представимое результирующим типом.
>
> В противном случае, если `E1` имеет знаковый тип и неотрицательное значение, а значение E1×2<sup>E2</sup> представимо в соответствующем результирующему типу беззнаковом типе, то это значение, преобразованное к результирующему типу, и служит результирующим значением; в противном случае поведение программы не определено.

Так понятнее? :)

Comment: Я посрался с **gcc bugzilla** по этому поводу : почему, говорю когда сдвигаю назад на 64 бита ничего не сдвигается, должен быть ноль ! Я задобался баг искать ! Это не наша забота говорят, процессор значит выпендривается. Приходится самому проверять sizeof(типа).

Comment: @AlexGlebe: Кто вам сказал, что "должен быть ноль"? Поведение всегда было не определено, причем эта неопределенность не придумана теоретиками стандарта языка, а основана на вполне реальной аппаратуре. "Сраться с gcc bugzilla" не разобравшись предварительно в этом уже давно вдоль и поперек разобранном вопросе - это странно.

Comment: Я владею английским, проблема непонимания мной Стандарта связана не с проблемами перевода, а с тем, что Стандарт как буд-то специально написан так, что даже несколько строчек мои мозги категорически отказываются понимать.